# WPF Custom Control: DependencyProperty of Collection type

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `CustomControl` which contains a `ListBox`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CustomList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I bind the `ItemsSource` with a property in the Code Behind:

```
public partial class CustomList : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CustomList( )
        {
            InitializeComponent( );
        }

        public ObservableCollection<object> ListSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue( ListSourceProperty );
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(CustomList.ListSourceProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged( "ListSource" );
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ListSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "ListSource",
             typeof( ObservableCollection<object> ),
             typeof( CustomList ),
             new PropertyMetadata( OnValueChanged ) );

        private static void OnValueChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            ( (CustomList)d ).ListSource = (ObservableCollection<object>)e.NewValue;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in my `MainWindow` I try to bind an `ObservableCollection` of "Articles" with my `CustomControl` and its ListSource DependencyProperty:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomList ListSource="{Binding Articles}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the error I get:

```
Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[WpfApplication1.Article]' and 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Object]'
```

If in the Custom Control I have `ObservableCollection<Article>` instead of `ObservableCollection<object>` it works.
So is there a way I can bind my Custom Control's DependencyProperty with an ObservableCollection of objects without having to specify the object's type?

Comment: You do not need to (should not in fact) implement INotifyPropertyChanged on DependencyProperties, also **do not** place any code in the setter of a dependency proeprty.

Comment: @H.B. Are you saying the dependency property will automatically implement the proper change notifications? Or, are you suggesting there is a better alternative?

Comment: @UB3571: Yes they do implement change notifications but they introduce thread affinity. The alternative is, as i said, `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: (As a resource for others) Regarding what goes into creating custom depend. props: I resolved by reading [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) which talks about custom dependency properties in entirety, and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) which talks about thread affinity, the threading model, and how to use the Dispatcher to your advantage. ( @H.B. you seem to be a little contradictory with the whole INotifyPropertyChanged comments...I still really have no idea what your trying to suggest with that...sorry.)

Comment: @UB3571: It's fairly simple, if you have a dependency property then that will fire change notifications upon setting it via the `SetValue` method, hence bindings to the property will update. If you do not have DPs your object needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to manually fire notifications in the setter of the property because the logic is not implemented in such a method like `SetValue`.

Comment: Simple would have been: No need for INotifyPropertyChanged on Dependency Properties as they have an inherent `SetValue` method, which is already doing it's job here by setting the local value set by the identifier. Nothing else is subscribing to the PropertyChanged event, so why raise one that is not thread-specific? I appreciate your comment responses but rather than telling people what to do to show you know an improvement, please help us improve ourselves by including the cause-effect reasoning behind your statements :) If you don't mind. Everything is "fairly simple" once you understand it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change type of ListSource to IEnumerable, then you can bind to any collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, you totally saved the day.

Comment: According to this Blog post , you should use  IList so you can populate in threw xaml  as well .

http://sshumakov.com/2012/11/13/how-to-create-dependency-properties-for-collections/